# Open Access Forms over Citrix in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to open a Access Forms over Citrix in Excel with VBA. I tried it with the below code but it gives me a runtime error at the second line. How can i Open Citrix Programms with VBA ?

```
Dim Access As Object
Set Access = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Access.Visible = True
Access.OpenCurrentDatabase "U:\Database1.accdb"
MsgBox "Datenbank geöffnet."
Access.CloseCurrentDatabase
Set Access = Nothing
```

Comment: Please include in your question: Which error in which line?

Comment: Do you have microsoft access installed on the computer you are running this from?

Comment: no MS Access is not installed on this Computer. Im accessing it via Citrix.